# why is nodetool (cassandra single node) throwing NameNotFoundException: 'jmxrmi'?

Tags: java, cassandra, nodetool

Ubuntu 14.04 3.19.0-30-generic running cassandra 3.0.2. and oracle java version "1.8.0_72"

i can see the port listening:
    127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26048/java

when i try checking status:

```
nodetool status                     
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - NameNotFoundException: 'jmxrmi'.
```

I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cassandra-and-run-a-single-node-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

NameNotFoundException: 'jmxrmi' is obscuring lower level problems.

The exception on one cassandra node went after a machine reboot (not all cassandra nodes needed the reboot to work though. On all machines i had to update java to oracle-java versions, all machines have had different java to begin with)

The exception on another node went away after removing /etc/hosts localhost binding.